# Export marker line to DXF

Tags: qgis, line, export, dxf

I was wondering if there is a way to export in DXF from QGIS (version 3.4.4) this type of line (The one with the "E" as a pattern).

[image: Line pattern fills i'm trying to export]

Here is how the line was created

[image: Strucutre of the line]

Currently, when I export this type of line, the symbols are not kept and the result is two superposed polylines: one which is the green polyline and the other which is a black polyline with the same thickness as the size of my symbols "E".